# PHP Pagination with 5 pages

Tags: php, mysqli

```
if( isset($_GET['page'] ) )
{ 
   $page = $_GET['page']-1;
   $offset = $recLimit * $page;$page = $_GET['page']+1;
}
else
{
  $page=2;
  $offset = 0;
}

$phpself = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if( $totalPages <= $noofpages )
{
   echo "Pages if less than or equal 5 : ";
   for($i=1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++)
   {
      echo  "<a href = \"$phpself?page=$i\">$i</a> |";
   }
}
else
 {
    $i=1;
    for($i; $i <= $totalPages; $i++)
    {
       echo  "<a href = \"$phpself?page=$i\">$i</a> |";
     }
  }
  ?><table border="1" cellpadding="8"><tr> <th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>E-mail ID</th><th>Verified</th>
```

I'm goin to make a PHP pagination but i've some problem, in this i want to show 5 pages and 4 records per page. and if we click on next button then it shows the remaining page. And there are total 7 pages.

Comment: First format your code..Do you think its readable..?You can see the preview below your question..

Comment: Please [format your code properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). It's highly unreadable.

Comment: if you want pagination php or javascript?

Comment: Sorry for that but Stackoverflow not allowed me to write codes in proper format. :-(

Comment: yes, i want PHP pagination without javascript...

Comment: Where does `$totalPages` and `$noofpages` come from? Please include that code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't really understand your code, here is something to get you started:

```
$items_per_page = 4;

/* Get the total number of records */
$result = mysqli_query("select count(*) as n from ...");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$total_count = $row["n"];

/* Calculate the total number of pages */
$total_pages = ceil($total_count / $items_per_page);

/* Determine the current page */
$current_page = intval(@$_GET["page"]);
if(!$current_page || $current_page < 1) { $current_page = 1; }
if($current_page > $total_pages)        { $current_page = $total_pages; }

/* Get the records for the current page */
$limit = $items_per_page;
$offset = ($current_page - 1) * $items_per_page;
$result = mysqli_query("select ... limit " . $offset . ", " . $limit);
```

To display the pagination links, use this:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)
{
    if($i > 1) { print(" | "); }
    if($current_page == $i) { print($i); }
    else { print('<a href="?page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a>'; }
}
```

Comment: is this possible to make a pagination like this :    1 2 3 4 [5] Next [6] 7 8 9 10 Next and when current page is 10 and when we click on next button it will appear like this [11] 12 13 14 15 and in this there are total 18 pages. thanks in advance.....